# SimpleForm in HAML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, simple-form, simple-form-for

I currently have a simpleForm in a HAML/RoR program:

```
= simple_form_for(@client, url: {action: "update" }, html: { method: :put }) do |f|
BLAH BLAH BLAH
= f.submit "Update Password", id: "submit", class: "btn btn-primary"
```

It functions. But on submit, it doesn't go where I want it to go.

When I change it to:

```
= simple_form_for(@client, url: admin_client_path(@client), html: { method: :put }) do |f|
```

It goes to the right place if I reload the form page, but the original place otherwise... It appears to actually change the password in both cases, at least...

Comment: this is strange .. what is your response from the controller ? `html` or `json` ?

Comment: I don't use `simple_form`, but is that the correct signature/use? From the docs, it seems like it would just be `= simple_form_for @client do |f|`. Also, I assume that `f.submit` is actually indented under `= simple_form_form`?

Comment: I'm not super familiar with it. We got the code from a contracting company and I'm taking over it... And yes, assume correct indentation... B-) cut and paste is hard.

Comment: sa77, I'm not sure, how would I tell? It goes to a new web page?

Comment: If someone could point me at useful documentation that lists possible arguments to simple_form_for, with explanations of what they do, that would be great, but the documentation on the github seems to just be a bunch of random examples, almost but not all of which have the form @jvillian suggests...